# iPod Touch Networking Without Wifi

Tags: networking, iphone, usb, ipod-touch

I'm in a wifi-less office. It's a no go.

Is there a way I can connect my iPod Touch to my network with out using wifi. Perhaps using my workstation as a proxy (without having to resort to the wireless card in it - also a no go).

Yes, I know the argument - "Just use the internet on your workstation". But there's other tool's I want to use on the iPod Touch that use the internet that aren't a web browser or e-mail client.

Comment: How would they figure out that you are sharing out the WiFi via your computer?

Comment: @Yar If I read it correctly, he's in a wifi-less office. It's not a matter of being "found out". It's a matter of not having wifi to connect to. @CodeSlave It seems the short answer is "no", but perhaps someone with more Apple kung fu knows of something outside the User Manual.

Comment: tagging ip-over-usb as well, cause, if you nix the wifi, you've only got one port to use.  unless you wanna try using the headphone jack as a std phone-line modem...

Comment: @Yar, I am one of the "they" and sharing out the WiFi is not possible as a matter of policy (no, I can't change the policy).

Comment: If your office has a policy against wifi, they've probably also got a policy against putting unauthorized devices on the network.  If you've got a business case for using your iPod Touch, talk to your manager about it.  If this is for personal use, your office likely has a policy on personal internet use, and you'll have to wait until you get home.

Comment: @David, Let me worry about the business case; the manager would like to make this work as well.

Comment: this would still be cool as heck to see a solution for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that was suggested (but later deleted) was to create and ad hoc (computer to computer) network with a wifi-network card.

This still does not act as a solution as it violates the no-wifi requirement.

At the present time, it does not appear possible to network a iPod Touch (or iPhone) without a wifi connection.

Comment: The Internet Sharing UI on the Mac literally says "Share your connection from Wi-Fi" *To* "iPhone USB" so it practially screams that this is possible.  However, I've yet to find someone who can explain how this works: https://skitch.com/e-tlianza/gh63m/sharing

Answer (score 2):

If you jailbreak your iPod, you can install OpenSSH and use it to tunnel your connection over USB/iTunes.

For info on jailbreaking:
http://blog.iphone-dev.org/

For info on tunneling via SSH:
http://alk2blog.blogspot.com/2008/08/ssh-to-get-your-iphone-online-via-usb.html

To address comments:

1) There is no reason you can't set up the proxy server for the WiFi interface.  Just find the interface that is enabled (there should only be one in this case)

2) This hack does work with 3.x firmware and iTunes 9.  (note the exceptions of phones/ipods that cannot be jailbroken yet)

Comment: +1 for more ssh coolness.  man, i'm learning a ton of new things about ssh today.

Comment: I'm not up for jail-breaking this one.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK!   
The explanation given states explicitly, that it needs a 3G network to work with in the first place.   Yeah, I know, it sounds wrong since SSH is used, but the author himself answers a question like this as negative.   THIS IS NOT THE CORRECT SOLUTION.

Comment: it uses the gprs/edge network to assign an IP address for the ssh to latch on to.  you might get away with using the wifi for this.  BUT... that hacking was done with 2.x firmwares, so by now it's moot anyway.

Comment: CodeSlave: if you aren't willing to jailbreak, then I think you are out of luck.  I updated the information above for others who might be interested in doing this as well.

Comment: No go.  You've nixed every possible option.  How are you expecting to connect to a device if you're not going to use it's sole means of connectivity?  My recommendation would've been a USB wireless adapter and a workstation in adhoc mode.