# iPhone and Mac internet sharing

Tags: mac, usb, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPod Touch Networking Without Wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/52410/ipod-touch-networking-without-wifi)

I want to share my internet connection with my iPhone via the usb cable. I have a Macbook pro. What do you think? Is this possible? And if yes, then how? Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/52410/ipod-touch-networking-without-wifi

Answer (score 1):

Not a programming question. But here's what you are after none the less:
http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/tethering.html

Not sure where you are located, but here's the fine print on that page: "Tethering is not currently offered in the U.S. and some other countries. See your carrier for availability."

Comment: He said he wants to share the wifi with the phone - from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

To share your internet from your computer with your phone you would share the connection over Wifi.

http://theappleblog.com/2008/05/22/create-a-wifi-hotspot-share-your-internet-connection-in-leopard/

You probably cannot do this over USB.  Wifi would be more usable.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without a jailbreak.  If your iPhone is still on OS 3.0, then you can just follow these instructions here: http://www.9to5mac.com/iPhone-3G-tethering

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers are correct. Just as an added FYI, AT&T should be coming out with tethering sooner or later. It was promised before the end of 2009 but never happened.

It is currently unknown if AT&T will be charging for this functionality when it is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to share the connection on your Macbook with your iPhone am I right in saying that? I actually was looking at that myself but I have a Windows laptop, there's an application called [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/index.html) that can share your connection with any nearby computers, its basically makes a hotspot. Its Windows 7 only, so you're going to have to have a windows partition on your laptop, if you do thats the best I can say. The iPhone doesn't have Wired internet support, it only has a Wifi Radio chip.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh, I was under the impression that you wished to use your phone's internet connection on your laptop. Now that I understand it is the other way around, I can explain this to you. Its very easy to do, and something I do all the time.

Unfortunately, there is no way to share your internet connection via the iPhones uSB cable, however you can do it using your computer's ethernet connection and airport card.

The most important thing is that your laptop has an ethernet (or Bluetooth PAN) connection. Without this,  you will not be able to share your connection over wifi to your phone.

To set up internet sharing between the two devices:

1. Launch System Preferences on your Mac and go to the "Sharing" section.
2. Under Internet Sharing, select Share my connection from Ethernet (or Bluetooth PAN) > To computers using AirPort (check the box).
3. To set up a password for, and name this network, click on the AirPort Options... button on the lower right.
4. Give your network a name, set the channel to automatic, and if you wish to encrypt the connection check the box and set a password.
5. Click "Ok" then check the box in the column to the left next to "Internet Sharing".
6. Click start and you should be ready to go. You will know if your AirPort menubar icon displays a grey upward pointing arrow.
7. Now go to Settings on your iPhone and go to the WiFi section. Join the network you created as though it was a normal WiFi network. Once you are joined, you are all set.

Note: this also works when you dont actually have an ethernet connection for your laptop, and you simply need your phone and your computer ont he same WiFi network as required by many applications. In this case, neither device will be on the internet, however, they will be on the same network. If you have any questions or need clarification on this process please let me know.